# Safari 9 Top Sites shortcut key gone missing or changed?

Tags: shortcut, macos, safari

Until version 9, pressing option+command+1 would bring up Top Sites. That does not work in version 9.

I see menu bar Bookmarks > Show Top Sites with no shortcut key listed next to it. That is worrisome.

However, in Preferences > Tabs I see an option named "Use ⌘-1 thru ⌘-9 to switch tabs". When I uncheck that, I get the old behavior of loading my top 9 favorite bookmarks instead of jumping to a tab. Because of this, I hold out hope there is an undocumented shortcut key for jumping to Top Sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add one yourself?

1. Open System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts and click add.
2. Select Safari, enter ‘Show Top Sites’ for the menu title and enter a keyboard shortcut.

This adds the shortcut to the menu option:

[image]

Comment: To answer: "Why not just add one yourself?" I did not know that I could. Now I do. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeff It was more of a conversational introduction to the answer than a direct question towards you :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting version 9.0, the shortcut for opening a Bookmark was remapped. You must now press the following key combination: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+(# of bookmark).

Comment: Excellent info! Can you figure out the new mapping (if any) to the old option+command+1 that loads Top Sites?

Answer (score 0):

"However, in Preferences > Tabs I see an option named "Use ⌘-1 thru ⌘-9 to switch tabs". When I uncheck that.."

Thanks for the info on this!  You saved me a lot of time...